# Error while publishing to chrome web store

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

I get an error while publishing my demo project (a google apps marketplace application) in chrome web store to my own domain. I get the below error.

"API Console project with the id specified in the manifest's api_console_project_id field, does not have Google Apps Marketplace SDK enabled."

I have enabled Google Apps Marketplace SDK and Google Apps Marketplace API as well for the particular project.

Also, I have not gotten my application reviewed by google. Do I have to get this reviewed even if I am publishing to my own domain?

Update:

*Manifest file*

```
{
    "name": "Demo of single sign on",
    "version": "0.3",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Demo of single signon",
    "icons": {
        "128": "images/big.png",
        "16": "images/small.png"
    },
    "container": ["DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE"],
    "api_console_project_id": "681817309175",
    "app": {
        "launch": {
            "web_url": "https://demoappnamehere.appspot.com"
        }
    }
}
```

[image: sdk settings]

[image: developer console]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your manifest, screenshots of the marketplace SDK configuration in Cloud Console and screenshots of the "overview" section of the CLoud Console ?

Comment: @David - I have added screenshots and manifest details.

Comment: I have a few more APIs enabled in my test project : Google+, BigQuery, Google Cloud SQL, Google Cloud Storage, Google Cloud Storage JSON. My bet would be that the Google+ API is required, can you enable it and try to publish again ?

Comment: Thanks @David. I have the google+ api already enabled as per the screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that... Honestly everything seems correct. Have you tried asking on the Google Group ? If you find a solution please post it here or on my blog post, I'm sure it will help other people.
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/community

Comment: @plspl Did you resolve this

Comment: @Joe - Sorry, didn't get a chance to work on this again.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently, Google Apps Marketplace SDK must not only be *enabled*, but also *configured*.

So:

- Go to the [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/).
- Select your project.
- Go to APIs and auth > APIs
- In the All APIs tab, use the search box to find the Google Apps Marketplace SDK and click it.
- Click Enable API. If you followed the recommendation in the error message in the Marketplace, you already did all this.
- Still in the Google Apps Marketplace SDK page, select the API Configuration tab and then click the link to go to the original console.
- In this new form, make sure to fill all required fields (alright, click "Save" at the bottom and see what happens).

I have tested a bunch of other "solutions" before I could make this work. Just in case the procedure above doesn't work as is, here what I also did in the developer console:

- Enable the Google Cloud Deployment Manager API
- Enable the Drive SDK

Comment: Thanks. that helped. the whole process to publish a simple add-on is so complicated!

Answer (score 1):

The ID in `"api_console_project_id": "681817309175",` doesn't look correct. Have you confirmed this matches the 'Project ID' noted in the 'Overview' section of the API console (top left of the page)?

Comment: Added another screenshot at the bottom that shows the project ID. Its same as the one in manifest file.

Comment: Apologies, now that I take a closer look, I can see it's actually in the App ID in your original screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

[image: api_console_project_id]

api_console_project_id != projectid

api_console_project_id == projectnumber

Answer (score 0):

In the first screenshot, you need to upload all application icons (32x32, 48x48...), specify TOS Url, add any OAuth2 scopes your app requests and at least select either "Universal Navigation Extension" or "Drive Extension". Remember to click 'save' button at the bottom and make sure changes are successfully saved.