# Publish a Spreadsheet Add-on in the Chrome Store

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

I'm trying to publish a Spreadsheet Add-on following the [the app scripts documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish#complete_application_and_publish_your_add-on) but I get this error:

> Please fix the following errors:
>
> - API Console project with the id specified in the manifest's api_console_project_id field, does not have Google Apps Marketplace
>     SDK enabled. api_console_project_id

Here you can see a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3w3h.png

Inside the documentation it says:

> Do **not** upload a file in the Upload section at the top of the page;
>   Apps Script generates this file automatically for you and uploading a
>   separate file will cause the publication to fail.

As far as I know, the *api_console_project_id* is inside the *manifest.json* but it says that I should not upload anything, right? (developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing#the_manifest_file)

Does anyone know what do I have to do or why I can not publish?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry I didn't saw your comment till now Mogsdad!

### Here is the solution

I have found the answer to my problem (I swear I was looking for an answer during the whole day). Anyway, what I had to do was described in [Publishing Add-ons for Domain-Wide Installation.](http://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/domain-wide#before_you_publish)

This question gave the the clue:

[Error while publishing to chrome web store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635068/error-while-publishing-to-chrome-web-store)